# Shuffling an arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist, shuffle

Using an ArrayList, I need to subdivide a deck into two sections, one top section, and one bottom section. The top section will be the front of the ArrayList `arr`. If the size of the ArrayList `arr` happens to be odd, the top section size must be one more than the bottom section. Below you will see a few more specifications, there seems to be a slight logic error, but I'm having trouble figuring out where. As you can see, I have pretty much all of the code written and I feel as though this should be working. I need to shuffle without using collections.

Comment: I am getting a null pointer on this line: arr.add(i, topHalf.get(x)); because topHalf is an empty list at this point.

Comment: @LeHill i edited the for loop with arr.size()/2 as of now, is that good?

Comment: Make sure both for loops use that, then you get no null pointer. The bottomHalf is larger list when I use an arr of odd length.

Comment: @LeHill yeah, but just for the case the topHalf would have to be larger, in the case of it arr being of an odd size, I used arr.size()/2 +1 for that loop

Comment: Exactly. That would be the simplest change to this code to get it working.

Comment: @LeHill thank you, because from what I could tell I knew the rest of the code was logically correct

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i =0; i<topHalf.size();i++){
```

`topHalf.size()` will return 0 because you have no elements in it yet. When you initialize it you are just allocating a size for the underlying array but the arraylist will have a size of 0...

Comment: The ArrayList 'arr' actually has a predetermined size, so topHalf.size() should already have half that size.

Comment: @yarcenahs `size()` returns the number of elements in the list, not the length of the underlying array.

Comment: @yarcenahs yes or `(arr.size()/2 + 1)` depending on if the arraylist is odd or even...

Answer (score 0):

As an aside you could use the sublist method.

```
// divide by two and round up
int middle = (int)(arr.size() / 2.0f + 0.5f);

ArrayList<Battleable> topHalf = arr.sublist(0, middle);
ArrayList<Battleable> bottomHalf = arr.sublist(middle, arr.size());
```

Comment: Thank you, but I believe I can still achieve the right execution without it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the 'sublist' method. You can do:

```
Double middle = Math.ceil(new Double(arr.size())/2);<br>
topHalf = arr.subList(0, middle.intValue());<br>
bottomHalf = arr.subList(middle.intValue(), arr.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

The only change I would have made is adding a ternary operator to (simplify?) the code a little bit:

```
ArrayList<Battleable> topHalf = new ArrayList<Battleable>();
int topSize = arr.size() % 2 == 0 ? arr.size()/2 : (arr.size()/2)+1;
for(int i = 0; i < topSize; i++) {
    topHalf.add(i, arr.get(i));
}

ArrayList<Battleable> bottomHalf = new ArrayList<Battleable>();
int count = topHalf.size();
int bottomSize = arr.size() - topHalf.size();
for(int i = 0; i < bottomSize; i++) {
    bottomHalf.add(i, arr.get(count));
    count++;
}

int x = 0, y = 0;
int end = arr.size();
for(int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    if(I % 2 == 0) {
        arr.add(i, topHalf.get(x));
        x++;
    } else {
        arr.add(i, bottomHalf.get(y));
        y++;
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the final loop be arr.size() instead of the arr.size()/2? That would just run through half of the ArrayList

Comment: You are right. That last bit of logic kept throwing a IndexOutOfBoundsException, so I circumvented that. I updated the code to fix that too.